# Documentation GCP Service Account Delegation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I need a documentation explaining when to use the Service Account Delegation or domain-wide delegation in Google Cloud Platform from any important source.

Looking for I couldn't find when you need/is recommended to use them in any document of a certain importance.
This is a problem because one's own superior will never accept a request recommended by a nobody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three areas that I use delegation. Two of these areas delegation is mandatory and for one delegation is normally used.

**G Suite:**

To perform actions on accounts in G Suite by a software application requires using a service account and delegation:
[Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation)

Warning: This gives a person (service account) significant power and should only be granted with consideration and where required.

**Access Tokens:**

To create short-lived access tokens normally uses delegation (think AWS STS):
[Delegated request permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#sa-credentials-delegated)

**Data Signing:**

To use signing (use a service account private key) requires delegation (called impersonation in this case):
[Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)